# Error booting ghcjs in nixos from a stack project

Tags: haskell, cabal, nix, nixos, ghcjs

I'm encountering an error running the boot stage of GHCJS in Nixos. GHCJS is being installed by stack with:

```
stack setup
```

And it fails during "installing stage 0" with:

```
solver must be one of: modular
```

My stack.yaml looks like:

```
resolver: lts-7.19
compiler: ghcjs-0.2.1.9007019_ghc-8.0.1
compiler-check: match-exact

(...)

setup-info:
  ghcjs:
    source:
      ghcjs-0.2.1.9007019_ghc-8.0.1:
        url: http://ghcjs.tolysz.org/ghc-8.0-2017-02-05-lts-7.19-9007019.tar.gz
        sha1: d2cfc25f9cda32a25a87d9af68891b2186ee52f9
```

I've read that this was due to an [incompatibility between cabal-install 2.0 and GHCJS](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/28098). Even though I've been unable to find a way to fix it. Is there any way to make it build?

Comment: What version of stack you are using ? Try using the latest version if you aren't using that already..

Comment: I'm using 1.5.1, which is the latest.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/7h53s3/haskell_gui_advice/